# BeginCollectionItem Error MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm starting out and trying to follow [Steve Sanderson's blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) but it's in MVC2 and I'm using 5 so I can use Dynamic CRUD on partials.

I'm getting an error on `@Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow", item)` stating that the expression doesn't return a value to sender.

Where am I going wrong? Sure it's simple but want to get a grasp on how to use this functionality.

*Code:*
Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Gift>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Gift List</h2>
    What do you want for your birthday?

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="editorRows">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow", item)
        }
    </div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "BlankEditorRow", null, new {id = "addItem"});
    <input type="submit" value="Finished" />
}

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#addItem").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
            });
            return false;
        });
        $("a.deleteRow").live("click", function () {
            $(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove();
            return false;
        });
    </script>
}
```

partial:

```
@using HierarchicalControlsDemo.Helpers

<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("gifts"))
    {
    Item: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name);
    Value: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { size = 4 });
    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
    }
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class Gift
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class GiftController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Gift
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var initialData = new[]
            {
                new Gift {name = "Tall Hat", price = 39.95},
                new Gift {name = "Long Cloak", price = 120.00}
            };
            return View(initialData);
        }
        public ViewResult BlankEditorRow()
        {
            return View("GiftEditorRow", new Gift());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your model has a property `name` (lower case) but you partial has `x => x.Name` (upper case) Is that a typo? Have you declared `@model Project.Models.Gift` in the partial?

Comment: Yes that's just a typo - sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RenderPartial()` return `void` (it writes to the Response stream) so the correct usage is

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial(...); }
```

Aleternatively, you need to use `Partial` which return a `string`

```
@Html.Partial(...)
```

Side note; Your script to delete items will notwork for dynamically created elements and should be

```
$('#editorRows').on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {
    $(this).closest('.editorRow').remove();
});
```

Comment: Sorry called away for a meeting - will update code and give it a try - thank you.

Comment: Now I get `An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpCompileException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code` against the partial `@Html.Partial("GiftEditorRow", item)`

Comment: From a bit of digging it seems like the partial is infinitely looping and eventually missing an `}` somehow.

Comment: That error is not related to the code you have shown. You need to show your real code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting those errors in the comments of Stephen's answer is because you have an unexpected/non-readable code in your partial. Change to the below:

```
 @using HierarchicalControlsDemo.Helpers
@model Project.Models.Gift

<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("gifts"))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m =>m.name);
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.name);
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.price);
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.price);
    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Ha - that was the issue.