# Partial Display Not Returning to Index using BeginCollectionItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Updated Code** - if I use a button then the AJAX call doesn't work, never hit in chrome debug, if I use an action link to try and add the partial view it sends me to the partial view on its own, not within the Index as expected.

`<input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add" />`

rather than

`@Html.ActionLink("Add", "RequestedIpManager", null, new {id = "addItem"});`

Trying to put BeginCollectionItem into practice by using a more complicated model structure that in the online guide.

I've come undone with how the add item button is behaving - it doesn't return to index after going to the partial.

So I am ending up just in the partial view, the way I'm handling the code is the same as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988600/begincollectionitem-error-mvc/).

How can I get this to return to the Index? The only difference is with the Index model which ISN't IEnumerable, but the object is, I am I using it incorrectly?

**Code:**

**Index**

```
@model Project.Models.Pa_Ipv4
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="ui-block-a">
                    <p>Company Name</p>
                    <span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.companyDetails.name)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.companyDetails.name)
                    </span>
                </div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div id="editorRows">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.requestedIps)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("ReqIpView", item)
                    }
                </div>
                <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add" />
                </div>
            }
            <br />
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#addItem").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: @Url.Action("RequestedIpManager"),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
                });
                return false;
            });
            $('#editorRows').on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {
                $(this).closest('.editorRow').remove();
            });
    </script>
}
```

**Partial**

```
    @model Project.Models.IpAllocation
@using HierarchicalControlsDemo.Helpers
<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("requestedIps"))
    {
        <div class="ui-grid-c ui-responsive">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.subnet)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cidr)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.mask)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-d">
                <span>
                    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">Dlt</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Pa_Ipv4 paipv4 = new Pa_Ipv4
            {
                requestedIps = new List<IpAllocation>
                {
                    new IpAllocation {cidr = "", mask = "", subnet = "", allocationType = "requestedIp"}
                },
                existingIps = new List<IpAllocation>
                {
                    new IpAllocation {cidr = "", mask = "", subnet = "", allocationType = "existingIp"}
                }
            };
            return View(paipv4);
        }
public ViewResult RequestedIpManager()
        {
            return View("ReqIpView", new IpAllocation());
        }
```

**Models** - for clarity

```
    public class Pa_Ipv4
    {
        public Details companyDetails { get; set; } // just a basic holding class for company input
        public List<IpAllocation> requestedIps { get; set; }
    }
public class IpAllocation
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string allocationType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string subnet { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string cidr { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string mask { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your generating partials for typeof `Requested` but partial has `@model Project.Models.ClassA` (assume that's a typo?) and you use `BeginCollectionItem("requesteds")` but the property name is `requested` (not plural) so that also does not work. And your ajax call is to a method named `RequestedManager()` but all you have shown is `RequestedIpManager`. You need to post your real code!

Comment: Apologies I've made the changes - this is code from a project I'm trying to improve to make it dynamic (and actually work) but it's a demo/test project before I take it over to the live one.

Comment: So are you claiming that when you click the add button your actually redirect to a view showing just the partial (as opposed to staying on the same page)?

Comment: Yes, that's what's happening. I'm using the code you fixed for me in the mentioned question to replicate this on a model which isn't ienumerable, but contains an object property that is ienumerable.

Comment: You obviously not hitting the script. Replace the link with `<button type="button" id="addItem">Add</button>` and in the script use `url: '@Url.Action("RequestedManager")',` and see it it works

Comment: No that isn't working - however is the way I've gone about using the IEnumerable correct? If it's a script issue, which seems likely now you mention it then I can faff and try and sort it, just didn't know where to start as it was extremely similar to a working example.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with you use of the collection (which is actually `List<RequestedManager)`) and there is nothing wrong with the code you have shown but since both this and your last question did not include the real code, I suspect you still have not shown everything correctly.

Comment: I have now updated the code and my findings to show exactly (skinnier) what I'm using, all that's cut is extra divs.

Comment: Have no idea why you have accepted the answer your have - it just suggesting bad practice by hard coding the url instead of using `@Url.Action()`

Comment: Because it fixed the issue I was having, `@Url.Action` wasn't being read by the browser properly, it wasn't a string which I believe Url needs to be. What's the danger of hard coding the URL, it's not going to change?

Comment: If that the case then there is some other issue which you have not told us (not surprising since you have a habit of not posting real code). `@Url.Action()` will always generate the correct url relative to your current page and performs other checks, for example against your route definitions.

Comment: Perhaps either your `RequestedIpManager()` method is in a different controller from the method that rendered the initial page (in which case you need to specify the controller name as well) or your script is in a separate external file, in which case you include the url in the button - `<input type="button" id="addItem" data-url="@Url.Action(..)" value="Add" />` and then retrieve it in the script using `var url = $(this).data('url')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87048/discussion-between-jammandtea-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few little things wrong with this.

The ajax isn't working properly because the `@url.action(actionName)` isn't returning a string value on the browser which isn't valied - check chrome debugger.

**Edit** - changed to best practice URL.

Your section script should look like the below to avoid this:

`$(function() {
            $('#addItem').on('click', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Url.Action("RequestedIpManager")',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });`

Then in your controller, make the following changes as it stands your controller was returning a full view, so when the click was actually working, you were getting a whole page in there:

`public ActionResult RequestedIpManager()
        {
            return PartialView("ReqIpView", new IpAllocation());
        }`